# Libgdx - How to move object forward by direction?

Tags: libgdx, rotation, move, forward

Example: I have 3 object with 3 rotation so how can i move object forward by object's direction like that.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTWDf.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using sprites to hold to values of each object, set the x/y += direction you want the objects to travel. Otherwise, if you are drawing the image through a spritebatch you can use batch.draw(texture, x, y) and set the x and y coordinates that way.